# Module not found, even when I have installed it

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, xlib, pyautogui

I'm trying to use the PyAutoGUI lib, and I get this error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Xlib'`.  I have already tried `sudo apt-get install python-xlib`, `pip3 install xlib` and all the instalation commands that i have found, but no result.

This is the error I get

```
File "/root/.../_pyautogui_x11.py", line 7, in <module>
from Xlib.display import Display
```

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Xlib'`

Solution:
What I did finally is install the xlib library from PyCharm, and it worked.

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on Stack Overflow please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and if not already done, [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

Confirm xlib was actually installed in this folder

```
Python/Lib/site-packages
```

If it was installed, make sure the name you're importing is typed exactly as the name of the xlib folder/module. For example: if the folder is named xlib, you import this way;

```
from xlib.display import Display
```

NOT this way

```
from Xlib.display import Display
```